# Add migration not recognized my changes when I add class to my model but ok when I add property to an existing class

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I try to add a class and apply add-migration to update database but the migration script generated is up and down empty.

I have deleted migration history table and update database, then apply modifications to my model by adding new class and generate add-migration script but it's KO.

Really strange is when I add a property to an existing class, add-migration detect the changes and the script generated is not empty.

please help

Comment: You have a DbSet for the new class?

Comment: no I don't have dbset for the new class

Comment: EF should pickup changes if you use a DbSet or link to the new class from another.

Comment: ok I have added a DBset It's ok now. Tks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem . 
I think you have to pay attention to your mapping . may be your relation is with type of HasRequired which should be changed to hasOptional.
Sample => Mapping with Mistake :

```
            this.HasRequired(t => t.Term)
                .WithMany(t => t.UserDemands)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.TermId);
```

Correct Mapping :

```
            this.HasOptional(t => t.Term)
                .WithMany(t => t.UserDemands)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.TermId);
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same problem with the following solution:

In the Context.cs

add the following code:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<NameOfClass>()
    .Map(c=>
    {
    c.ToTable("NameOfClass");
    });
```

With this migrations found the new Classes.